# How to get the index KEY columns by query in db2 v6.1?

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am trying to get the Index key columns from Data base by using SQL.

Currently I am doing in manual way.

Please help me to get all the index key details from query.

FYI (SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES/SYSIBM.kEYS are not working, SYSIBM.tables working)

Comment: What do you mean, "not working". Show the error-code and your query.  Also, which operating-system runs your Db2-server (Z/OS, i-Series, Linux/unix/Windows) ?

Comment: If your Db2-server runs on iSeries, check out `QSYS2.SYSKEYS` see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/db2/rbafzcatsyskeys.htm

Comment: Wow! It really works "QSYS2.SYSKEYS". You are like god to me now.

Comment: It runs in  i-Series. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Db2-server runs on i-Series then checkout QSYS2.SYSKEYS .  See details at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsyskeys.htm)